# i need to compare two variables of two different models flutter

Tags: list, flutter, compare

I have to compare the data of a model with another model and pull out the list of those == between them

in UserAsset I have to take the name which is a string and compare it with Brand's enabled_assets which, however, is a list of strings. If they are the same, I save them to show later.

I don't know how to compare everything .. could you give me a hand?

```
UserAsset(
    name: 'String',
  )

  Brand(
    enabled_assets: ['String','String'],
  )
```

Comment: Could you explain your objective a bit better there ? You need to compare UserAsset's name with Brand's enabled_assets, that much is clear, but what is the condition to save them ? Does *all* the assets in enabled_assets need to be the same as the UserAsset's name ? What do we save, the Brand instance, the UserAsset instance, the String that we validated ?

Comment: @MeïM. yes that's right, I would need to show only the UserAsset names that are also present in Brand. so to answer your question I think I have to return a list of UserAsset

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for answering my comments. It helped to see what you really needed.

The main thing you will want to use here is the `contains()` method on `Iterable`. It allows you to check if an element is part of an `Iterable` (in your case a `List`), returns true if it does, false otherwise.

Here is some sample code, that you can also find on this DartPad:
https://dartpad.dev/?id=03e29d48ba988fc36ae983ef96b4bc6b

```dart
class UserAsset {
  final String name;

  UserAsset(this.name);
}

class Brand {
  final List<String> enabled_assets;

  Brand(this.enabled_assets);
}

void main() {
  // Definition of our brand and its allowed assets.
  final brand = Brand(
    [
      "Nintendo Entertainment System",
      "Super Nintendo",
      "Nintendo 64",
      "Game Boy",
      "Game Boy Color",
      "Gamecube",
      "Game Boy Advance",
      "Nintendo DS",
      "Wii",
      "Nintendo 3DS",
      "Wii U",
      "Nintendo Switch",
    ],
  );
  
  // List of user assets to be tested
  final userAssets = [
    UserAsset("Megadrive"),
    UserAsset("Nintendo DS"),
    UserAsset("Xbox One"),
    UserAsset("Gamecube"),
  ];
  
  // List that will contain the assets we validated
  final foundAssets = <UserAsset>[];
  
  // We iterated on the list of userAssets
  for (final asset in userAssets) {
    // If the enabled_assets of the brand contains the user's asset, validate it
    if (brand.enabled_assets.contains(asset.name)) {
      foundAssets.add(asset);
    }
  }
  
  // Display the validated user assets
  for (final asset in foundAssets) {
    print(asset.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the meantime, thank you for your help. ok I think it can work, I just have one more problem. I already have a model in the class where I'm working. while I have to assign the other by making this call: 
https://pastebin.com/eU0bn8Zh

this is a Future. I'm trying to assign my 'userAssets' variable as well as your example but I have an error on the Future .. I have no idea how to assign my list and populate it with data from that Connection ()

Comment: @ste Not sure to understand the problem you still have here ! Could't you just await the Future to get your List<Brand> and work from there ?